# Why would Microsoft.WITDataStore32.dll crash VS2019 on launch, and what do I need to do to fix this issue?

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to open VS2019. However, every time I do I get the following error message -

[image]

I've opened the Event Viewer, and traced the error to this file -

[image]

This is a fairly new issue, only starting to present yesterday. I can't just uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio, as it's installed in a Citrix Environment and I do not have the necessary access. I've tried deleting my login folder, which seemed like it might work as it popped open the login dialog and let me enter my credentials, only to immediately crash again.

I have no clue what to do here to fix this, and apparently I am the first person on planet earth to be experiencing this issue in this way, as Google has turned up absolutely nothing.